# Babel: how to use two fonts for same language

Tags: babel

I have some code to write in both english and arabic in babel:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english, provide=*, bidi=basic, layout=counters.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Traditional Arabic}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Temp}
This is a temporary chapter. Number 256.

\section{Section A}
Here is the first section. We want to start writing in Arabic 256:

\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
نريد أن نكتب \underline{بالعربية} رقم ٢٥٦ أو 256
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item هذا هو الرقم الأول256
        \item هذا هو الرقم الثاني ٢٥٦
        \end{enumerate}
\end{otherlanguage}

\section{Section D \foreignlanguage{arabic}{هذا هو الفصل ٢٥٦}}
\end{document}
```

My question is: I defined 2 fonts for english and arabic, how can I write some arabic phrase in a new font?

Comment: You can add a new font family via `\babelfont`, then use it as a font switch. For example add to the preamble `\babelfont{alt}{Amiri}`, then you can use this font with `\foreignlanguage{arabic}{\altfamily هذا هو الفصل ٢٥٦}`.

Comment: Please put this as answer so that I accept it.